# $ P\in M_n$ is positive definite Hermitian matrix, such that $P^{−1}AP$ is normal. $ \Rightarrow $ $A$ is normal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $ P\in M_n$ be positive definite Hermitian matrix, such that $P^{−1}AP$ is normal.

Can we say that $A$ is normal?

Answer (score 2):

No, not necessarily.  For instance, consider $P=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.  Writing $A=PBP^{-1}$, then $B=P^{-1}AP$ is normal.  But you can easily compute that $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 1/2 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ is not normal.

Comment: Thanks. Can we Show that $A$ is diagonalizable by similarity?

Comment: Over the complex numbers, yes. A matrix that is similar to a diagonalizable matrix is diagonalizable.